# Disable USB charging

Tags: usb, charging, file-system, system

For some reasons not related to the battery life, I need to disable the battery charging when a USB host is connected to my phone (a rooted Nexus 4). Taking a look around on the internet ([link1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=787641&page=2), [link2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/how-can-i-avoid-the-battery-charging-when-connected-via-usb)), it looks like I should modify a system file. I have found a series of interesting files located in `/sys/class/power_supply/battery` and `/sys/class/power_supply/usb`, that could be the right ones to be modified in order to achieve the usb charging disabling (e.g. `/sys/class/power_supply/usb/present 0/1`).

Has anyone tried something like that (control the usb charging via software and modify such system files)? Which is the best way to modify those system files? Should I use the adb shell or another tool?

I tried the "root explore" app in order to modify those files, however when I modified a file (after changing its permissions), it was automatically kept back to its original value.

Comment: While this may or may not contribute to the question, I'm curious as to why you want to disable USB charging.

Comment: What I have here is something more similar to an embedded system: a phone (USB ACCESSORY) and a piece of hardware (USB HOST), connected through USB. The phone battery supplies the attached hardware through a specific connection (Vdd). However, the USB HOST is supposed to supply (or charge) the phone through the VBUS line of the USB. What I want to avoid is a loop of charge between phone and attached hardware. Despite the attached hardware is the HOST, it is the Android phone that supplies the whole system. Hope my explanation was clear to you.

Comment: /sys is a virtual file system where the kernel exposes knobs and switches to alter and look up kernel configuration. You can't change the file permissions. I guess your nexus phone is unlocked and rooted. The charging circuit is probably based on a Maxim chip that *may* be configured. There are altered kernels available which allow overriding of the detection for power charging. The reverse should also be possible. You may need to patch and recompile the kernel though.

Comment: Franco Kernel for the nexus 4 allows fast charging, sources are available. maybe you can have a look at it and figure out how to switch it off: https://github.com/franciscofranco

Comment: Here's the driver: https://github.com/franciscofranco/mako/blob/nightlies-4.3-JWR/drivers/power/bq51051b_charger.c

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316355/disable-usb-charging

Answer (score 8):

I just tried and found that you need to modify a file:
`sys/class/power_supply/usb/device/charge`

its default content is '1' which means 'enable charging'
you need to set it to '0' to 'disable charging'

```
$ su

$ echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/device/charge
```

I tested on Nexus 4 and it's working successfully.

Comment: I can confirm that `echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled` works for me, on a Sony Z1 Compact with CM11. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Please note that the /sys interface is virtual and does not persist reboots

Answer (score 4):

```
adb shell dumpsys battery set ac 0; dumpsys battery set usb 0;
```

Comment: These commands are interesting, but they don't really affect charging! You could also do `dumpsys battery set level 42` and the Android will think it's 42% charged, regardless of real battery state. Do `dumpsys battery reset` to return to normal.

Comment: Also, these fake changes freeze reported battery state and get recorded in battery statistics, which might mess them up and result in wrong "time remaining" predictions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will work with your particular phone's charger, but often with cables that transfer both power and data, there are separate cords inside the cable for power, and data.

I'm not especially interested in tearing up my phone charger to confirm my idea, but you could try stripping part of the cable, identifying and cutting the power cords inside the cable, and wrapping it back up with electric tape.

There is likely a *way* easier means of doing this, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: There are 4 pins in USB generally - 2 for 5v power and 2 for data.

Comment: If you cut Vbus and Ground it will also stop the data lines from working. USB cable connection is detected from the power (see the A-connector, the power pins are slightly longer so they will connect first).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not something you can change in software since the would phone charge when plugged into a computers USB port. You'd probably need to get your hands dirty and short a connection or two on the phone itself.

Comment: Yes it can also be done via software. Look at this app for rooted Nexus 4    [stopCharge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.guille.stopcharge)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
adb shell dumpsys battery set usb 0;    // for disabling USB charging and

adb shell dumpsys battery set usb 1;    // for enabling USB charging

Comment: This is easy, but unfortunately it does not disable charging. It only makes it look like it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my colleague, who is an expert in battery driver. On our Nut Pro 2, whose kernel version is 4.4.21, the node for battery charging on/off is: `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/input_suspend`.

Comment: Same here on my Xiaomi Redmi K20 Pro with 4.14.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use a shottky diode between pin 1 with the blocking side towards the accessory. that way the pin one gets a 5v signal so communication works, but there will be NO current flowing from the accesory to your phone. or if you want it the other way just place the diode in the different direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue in hardware by modifying the pins on the micro-USB connector side. One obvious way is to not connect Pin#1 (VBUS) and the other way is to ground Pin#4 (ID) to pretend your host (PC) is an OTG device. If you do that, you **have to** disconnect Pin#1 (VBUS) otherwise one, if not both, of your devices will get burned.

As for the command line solution, you just have to find the right (device dependent) `/sys/...` files to play with. But as already mentioned, you need write access and root permissions to change these, and whatever you do it will only last until next reboot or change of USB peripheral.

Comment: The hardware solution suggested is incorrect. Almost every Android phone out there is a USB device that gets the power supply from USB hosts (e.g. laptops), thus working in Accessory mode. If you cut VBUS line the USB data communication stops working. I have tested this myself. I would say the same for the other way (ID pin) even though I did not test it.
You are right about the software solution, however not all Android phones have the `/sys/...` files necessary to do so (Nexus 4 yes, Nexus 5 no). Another solution should be the changing of the charging driver behaviour into the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the op, my Host who is connected via USB is also connected as a dummy battery. Can't simply use USB cable and no battery, android won't boot, nor does usb provide enough current.

You cannot fix this in software as Android will use Vbus during boot. Unless you also want to hack bootloader code.

The charging circuit needs to be modified to avoid usb charging vs battery voltage loop.

I confirmed on Galaxy S3 it requires 5V bus to enable data (d+ d-) it's part of USB standard.

OTG could solve the problem electrically but then the host client rules are not correct. Also this phone is able to OTG and charge (i use y-cable + gamepad)

Edit reference: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1863303

Comment: Will update once I figure out charging circuit changes

Answer (score -1):

No, It is not possible on devices which are not yet rooted. It uses Settings.System with ADB_ENABLED, but ADB_ENABLED is a Secure-System-Setting which can not be changed by a application.

Yes, It can be done on rooted phone.

There is need to add an permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.
I know you would be asking how do I do that:
Here is the link for a similiar app:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2&hl=en

Comment: What has `ADB_ENABLED` got to do with USB charging? Does the app you link allow to disable USB charging?

Comment: The app kinda allows you to disable usb charging after you alter write secure settings.

Comment: "Kinda"? What are the steps to follow?