# Can I disable charging peripherals via USB?

Tags: usb, charging, audio

I have an external DAC with it's own source of power. However when I connect it to the phone, it drains the phones battery.
Is it possible to disable charging via USB on a rooted phone? Or at least slow it down?

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 6, CyanogenMod

Comment: This should help http://android.stackexchange.com/a/133984/131553

Comment: Would it work the other way around? I mean it's a solution to charging from pc to mobile. I want to disable charging DAC(which is not using android) with my android phone.

Comment: I am not sure- you can try and post it as an answer if it works

Comment: so far I have tried limiting USB charging through boeffla config app and it stoped charging from PC but still the phone is providing power through USB.
Also I can't seem to be able to change "sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled" through terminal as a root even though the file is set to be writable

Comment: Could be that the file location is different

Comment: there is a file like that, however I can't seem to modify it

Comment: Can't say why unless it is Selinux playing up. I had a similar problem tracked by replacing the file. You can see that here http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127286/131553

Comment: what about limiting the charging so it won't drain the battery so fast?

Comment: Theoretically ,yes, not sure how. Another similar problem http://android.stackexchange.com/q/160459/131553