# Is it possible to limit power supplied by host connected with OTG cable?

Tags: usb, battery-life, usb-on-the-go

Is it possible, to lower the power that is supplied to the devices through the OTG Cable by messing around with the host? 
My Galaxy S3 is the host and this connection is draining battery well to fast, the device has it's own source of power but I can't disable the drain on this side.

Comment: Fiio X3 as DAC, it can't be changed on X3's side.
I know I can limit how fast is the phone charging through USB so it should be possible the other way around right?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates. It doesn't help you or the potential answerers or the site