# Disbale charging of phone by outlet

Tags: battery, charging

Is there any way I can disable charging by outlet in my phone by some software.
Kids keep making toy of my phone and I better have excuse that phone is discharged and not charging.I have android 7.
My phone has fixed battery it is one plus 3T.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Samsung J7 via USB but disable charging?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133661/how-to-connect-samsung-j7-via-usb-but-disable-charging)

Comment: you can remove battery from that.. and can show your phone is not charging :p

Comment: The question marked duplicate talks of a particular phone but the answer has generic approaches

Comment: It not duplicate that question is from PC to phone charging, mine is from OUTLET POWER

Comment: Adb command is still an option as mentioned in answer. There are also data only no power cables but I have never used them or studied

Comment: Or use apps like [fake battery low](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FakeBatteryLow)