# Plug Android smartpone into PC without loading | LineageOS

Tags: adb, charging, lineageos

I am using my main smartphone for developing Android apps and doing research.
I set everything up and searched for a specific option under *USB Preferences*, when connected to my computer.
As I don't want to drain the capacity of my smartphone, I'd kinda like an option like *Data transer, but do not load*, so that the battery can have normal battery cycles instead of always staying at 100% because it's connected to my computer.
However, I didn't find anything in the preferences or on the internet.

Does anyone know if there is an option for enabling `adb` to still function but disable charging while connected to the computer?

Btw, I am using LineageOS 17.1.

Comment: There are multiple questions here about disable USB charging, e.g. [Disable USB charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54902). As you have LineageOS you can root your device easily and try those solutions if they still work. On some Lenovo devices I have seen on option to disable charging unless battery is lower than 40% and stop charging when it reaches 60%).

Comment: Alright, thank you, @Robert. Indeed, I have access to a root adb shell, but I cannot root the device easily, as the root kit is no longer provided since LineageOS 17. I'll try those solutions, though.  My smartphone is indeed a Lenovo, but I couldn't find any of the options you described.