# How can i turn off charging when my phone connected to my computer?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung

I have Android device Samsung S4.

Is that possible to turn off Battery Charging when my phone connected to my Computer via USB Cable.

Any ways to turn off or disable it from settings?

Comment: This question has already been asked (and answered) multiple times. Please check e.g.: [Disable USB charging](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54902/16575) / [How can I avoid the battery charging when connected via USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15001/16575) / [our search engine](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=charge+connect) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to do so? I don't think it's possible, at least on an unrooted phone. You can refer to the below discussions, they might come handy:

- https://superuser.com/questions/429097/how-to-disable-usb-charging-of-external-devices-in-windows-7
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993635/how-to-stop-the-phone-from-charging-via-usb-programmatically
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=787641

Comment: It's because my phone already fully charged and when i connected to computer device give a warning message to turn off your charging your battery full.

Comment: Your link is useful for me...... thnx